# How to display email as hyperlink in php results

Tags: php, hyperlink

I have a database and I'm trying to display my email address as a hyperlink when the query doesn't match anything on our database. I'm using the following...

**PHP Code...**

```
else{ // if there is no matching rows do following

    echo "<br /><br /><br /><strong><h2>"."You have searched a term that is not in the database. Please contact <a href=\"mailto:email@domain.com" . htmlentities($_POST['email@domain.com']) . "\">".htmlentities($_POST['email@domain.com']) . "</a>, if you think this term should be added."."</h2></strong>";
```

**But, the results I get look like this...**

**"You have searched a term that is not in the database. Please contact , if you think this term should be added."**

Everything's there except the hyperlinked email address.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this..

```
else{ // if there is no matching rows do following
    $mail = htmlentities('email@domain.com');
    echo "<br /><br /><br /><strong><h2>" .
        "You have searched a term that is not in the database. Please contact <a href=\"mailto:$mail\">$mail</a>, if you think this term should be added.</h2></strong>";
```

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly. Why remove the `$_POST[]` though?

Comment: why you added the $_POST? If the mail address isn't send with the form(which doesn't make much sense for me..) you don't have to use $_POST

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="mailto:<?php echo $_POST['email_field_name']; ?>">
    <?php echo $_POST['email_field_name']; ?>
</a>
```

Although, you may want to provide some mechanism of email address obfuscation. This will provide a level of protection for your users from spam robot mining your email addresses. Usually addresses that are unprotected (as they are in the above example) will receive more and more spam as time goes on.

If the page that you are displaying them on is secured behind a login, this is much less of an issue.

Comment: This site will be located internally on an AD Server. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST['email@domain.com']` is probably undefined (or empty).

Don't you just want: `"email@domain.com"`?

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
$_POST['email@domain.com']
```

should be changed to this:

```
$_POST['email'];
```

where email is your form field. This will work only if you are getting value of email address from a previous page as a form field. If that is not the case then just replace $_POST['email@domain.com'] with "email@domain.com";

Comment: Done. The results still come up blank. Where do I add the text for my email?

Comment: do this:echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST); echo '</pre>'; to make sure $_POST has what you want in it

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST['email@domain.com']` should be `$_POST['email']`. And there shouldn't be `email@domain.com` after `mailto`. Your statement should be like this:

```
 echo "<br /><br /><br /><strong><h2>"."You have searched a term that is not in the database. Please contact <a href='mailto:" . htmlentities($_POST['email']) . "'>".htmlentities($_POST['email']) . "</a>, if you think this term should be added."."</h2></strong>";
```